# iOS GeoFencing: when user leaves the region in a subway

Tags: ios, gps, geofencing

What happens when user has no connection whatsoever and leaves the area I'm monitoring?

I am trying to implement something like "Significant location change" monitoring for devices without SIM card. So I'm basically, monitoring a region around a user. When he leaves the area, I'm getting his new location and starting monitoring new area around his new location.

And it seems to work fine, until I'm leaving that region without GPS or wi-fi connection (in a subway).

Also, I want my app to keep track while it is suspended, so I can't check for region after some time has passed. I'm using AppDelegate's didFinishLaunching with options callback to begin new region tracking.

Edit: My best idea for now is to couple CLVisit with CLRegion monitoring to check if user has already left the old region when he stops.